# arrange sequence of numbers such that sum of adjacent number is a prime number

Tags: algorithm, stl-algorithm, evolutionary-algorithm

What would be the best way to arrange a sequence of numbers such that the sum of any two adjacent number is a prime number 
E.g.: 7,6,5,2,1,4,3 is one such sequence for numbers between 1 to 7.

Comment: Have you tried this yourself? Also, are the numbers always in the range [1..n]?

Comment: First thing to notice - it must always be odd-even-odd numbers for this to be possible. If you have more odd than even numbers, you must start with even; etc.

Comment: Yes, please elaborate. I'm not sure this holds for arbitrary sequences [1..n], so I'm not quite sure what you're after...

Comment: Evolutionary algorithm doesn't seem the best thing to me. Also, definition of 'best' is required. Is it one-time task, or you have to do many runs for different n? How big n can be? One possible trick is finding cyclic sequences of range [N..M] so that (first+last) is also prime.

Comment: I believe you can solve it by **search algorithm**. Are they all positive numbers? We may add some pruning on it.

Comment: Refer this [link](http://nverma-tech-blog.blogspot.in/2014/01/coding-context-arranging-numbers-from-1.html) to get end to end solution.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I see it, the easiest way to tackle this problem is to break it into two parts that are more well defined:

1. Generate an undirected graph, so that each vertex is a number in this list of numbers and each edge links a pair of numbers that can be adjacent.  Or in other words, generates a graph that connects any two numbers that has a prime number sum.   This can be done in quite a straightforward manner by looping through 2 indices.
2. Find a [Hamiltonian path](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_path) for the aforementioned graph.  That is the sequence you want.  This is somewhat a well-studied problem and [a number of algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_path_problem) exist. You just need to pick one and there might be a native implementation in software like Mathematica.  This would be even faster than O(n^2).

Of course you can find multiple ways to speed up the first step, if you know a bit more about what kind of list of numbers you are dealing with.